# Cannot resolve symbol 'Cucumber'

Tags: java, android, gradle, cucumber

I wish to use Cucumber in my Android application. I have the below dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.5'
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.5'

testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:4.2.0'
testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
```

And I have a Runner class as with:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
```

But, it complains about:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Cucumber'
```

And when I add the `import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;` manually, it complains with the same reason. It seems that Cucumber.class does not exist in this library.

***What did I miss here?***

Answer (score -1):

Got it. it was in: `androidTestImplementation   'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.5'`